# Why does $\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{r^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$ converge to $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I'm being told that because the following series is the tail end of a convergent series, it converges to zero as $n$ gets large:

> $$\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{r^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$$

The tail end of which convergent series? $e^r$? If so, then the above series is actually every other term of the tail send of the power series for $e^r$, right?

Or how else to see that the above series converges to $0$? Or does the series sum to zero simply because as $n$ gets large, the number of terms get arbitrarily small?

Comment: Silly me, I just realised that I could've simply used the ratio test instead of trying to identify a standard series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{r^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$ is the Taylor series of $\sinh r$, the hyperbolic sine (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Taylor_series_expressions)), which converges for all real $r$.

But even the observation that it's half of the terms of $e^r$ is sufficient in this case: simply apply the [squeeze theorem](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Squeeze_Theorem/Sequences/Real_Numbers) with the zero series and the $e^r$ series:

In terms of the formulation in the link, put:

\begin{align}
x_n &= \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{r^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\\
y_n &= 0\\
z_n &= \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{r^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!} + \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{r^{2k+2}}{(2k+2)!} = \sum_{j=2n+3}^\infty\frac{r^j}{j!}
\end{align}

Since $z_n$ is the tail of $e^r$, it converges to zero, and the squeeze theorem tells us that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n = 0$, as desired.

---

As to "the number of terms gets arbitrarily small", that's quite incorrect. It's like saying that there are only finitely many natural numbers.

If this were correct, we would have $\displaystyle \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty 1 = 0$ as well, which of course is not true.

Comment: @Ryan I've edited to make the application of the squeeze theorem clearer.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: The comparison test is to establish convergence. The squeeze theorem is used here to obtain that the value of the limit is zero. They're just slightly different theorems. Both could've been applied here. // You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Quotient $|a_{k+1}/a_k| \leq \delta < 1$ for $k$ sufficiently large wrt to $r$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_n = \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty a_k$ (if it exists).

if $x_0 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ exists, by definition this means that the sequence $b_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ has a limit $l$. Since $x_n = l - b_n$ and $b_n \to l$, $x_n$ must converge to $0$.

So the sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $0$ because it's in the definition of "$x_n$ exists".

So I guess if you're even talking about your sequence, hopefully you know that it exists, and so the sequence converge to $0$. If not the problem is to show that $x_0$ exists, and you do that by comparing the finite sums to $e^r$ or to some other converging series like $\sum a2^{-k}$ for some big enough $a$